# Why do I keep getting arbitrary syntax errors in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, math, syntax

I am writing a simple script in python to return a GDP value. Starting on line 6, it gives a "Syntax Error" with no further elaboration. I commented out all of the lines with this issue (line 6-end) and on line 16, I got an "EOF while parsing" error. I'm really not sure what to do because I checked for mismatched delimiters, incorrect syntax, etc., but the only thing I could find was the way I did my print statements, but since they are both the same, and only one got a parsing error that is unlikely to be the case. Here is the code:

```
y_i = int(input("What year did your alt history begin?"))
y_f = 2014
p_i = int(input("Enter population of your territory starting from your alt history.")
p_g = int(input("Enter average population growth from year to year in a numerical value. No percentages.")
p_f = (p_i(p_g - y_f) ** 2)/(10000 * y_i ** 2)

print("This is your nation's population.", p_f, "If you got an error, check that you put in all inputs correctly.")

gdp_capita = int(input("What is your GDP per capita? Please use the number only, in your own currency.")


gdp = pop * gdp_capita

print("This is your nation's GDP.", gdp, "If you get an error, please check that you entered everything in correctly.")
```

Comment: "because I checked for mismatched delimiters": not very successfully, it seems..

Comment: On your third and fourth lines, you are missing a closing parenthesis.  Also on the line with `gdp_capita = ...`

Comment: Incidentally, `p_i(p_g - y_f)` won't work either-- that tries to call an integer.  You may be thinking of `p_i*(p_g - y_f)`.

Comment: Why is there an uncalled variable `pop` in the 3rd to last line?

Comment: It would probably have been easier to see where any issues were if you make the long text strings into short constants. IE: "What year did your alt history begin?" to something like START_YEAR_PROMPT.

Answer (score 0):

Your errors *are* in your syntaxing. You are missing close parentheses. On lines 3, 4, and 9, you have this: `int(input("...")`, **without the last close parentheses!** You are also trying to call an integer in line 5, with `p_f = p_i(p_g...)`. I assumed you were trying to multiply, so I put a multiplying sign there (an asterisk). Also, make sure you now that double asterisks means 'to the power of'. `2**3 = 8`, not `6`.

Change your code to this:

```
y_i = int(input("What year did your alt history begin?"))
y_f = 2014
p_i = int(input("Enter population of your territory starting from your alt history."))
p_g = int(input("Enter average population growth from year to year in a numerical value. No percentages."))
p_f = (p_i*(p_g - y_f) ** 2)/(10000 * y_i ** 2)

print("This is your nation's population.", p_f, "If you got an error, check that you put in all inputs correctly.")

gdp_capita = int(input("What is your GDP per capita? Please use the number only, in your own currency."))


gdp = pop * gdp_capita

print("This is your nation's GDP.", gdp, "If you get an error, please check that you entered everything in correctly.")
```

But you got it right in line 1 :)